# Command line tools for accessing APIs with Oauth support

Tags: api, command-line, oauth

I want to mess around with an API from the command line. I'm looking for a good command line tool with Oauth support.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend [oacurl](http://code.google.com/p/oacurl/) which allows you to make request from the command line. Although it is build to use Google services by supplying a properties file you can have it talk to any OAuth service.

I create a config file (eg service.properties):

```
consumerKey=mykey
consumerSecret=mysecret
requestTokenUrl=https://service/oauth/request_token
userAuthorizationUrl=https://service/oauth/authorize
accessTokenUrl=https://localhost/oauth/access_token
```

then with the JAR downloaded to the same directory, login:

```
java -cp oacurl-1.3.0.jar  com.google.oacurl.Login --service-provider=service.properties --consumer=service.properties
```

this should launch your browser and allow you to login and store your access token (along with other information) in ~/.oacurl.properties . Then you can request a URL using the access token with:

```
java -cp oacurl-1.3.0.jar  com.google.oacurl.Fetch https://service/protected/path
```

and it will use your access token to download it.

Comment: can you please help me in config file, as i only know what i have to put in consumer key and consumer secret, while what to put for others i am unaware, please help

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/decklin/curlicue

This is a nice tool for doing Oauth at command line

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get this working for Google :(